# JQuery controls associated to ASP.NET controls inside a TabContainer inside an UpdatePanel does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an `UpdatePanel` control on my page that contains some **ASP.NET** controls that I need to associate with **JQuery** controls (`DatePicker`, `TimePicker` ...):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function $(LoadDateAndTimePickers() {

    $("#" + '<%=fromDateTextBox.ClientID%>').datepicker();
    $("#" + '<%=toDateTextBox.ClientID%>').datepicker();
    $("#" + '<%=fromTimeTextBox.ClientID%>').timepicker({ showPeriod: true });
    $("#" + '<%=toTimeTextBox.ClientID%>').timepicker({ showPeriod: true }));

};

</script>
```

That is working fine on **IE**. However, that does not work on **Chrome** and **FireFox** as my **ASP.NET** controls are inside an `UpdatePanel`.

So, I have handled the `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) event inside the `UpdatePanel` to be able to make it work on the mentioned browsers.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().
                add_endRequest(LoadDateAndTimePickers)
        </script>

    .....

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

That has worked just fine. But, on other pages I am placing my **ASP.NET** controls inside an **AJAX ToolKit ** `TabContainer` control inside the `UpdatePanel`. Here `endRequest` handling stops working even if I place the handling script inside the `TabContainer` control.

Appreciate your help..

Comment: I've edited the question to incluse the script that associate _JQuery_ controls with _ASP.NET_ controls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand you question yet but this simply worked when i tried it in all browsers that jquery supports:

This is my content head:

```
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="ui/development-bundle/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is on the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlAjax" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID='txtMyFirstField'></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#pnlAjax input").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **to place the javascript out side the update panel.** The render of the update panel did not ensure that the javascript inside panel will run, and that why you register the endRequest, to re-run javascript initialization after the update panel updates him self.